# Unknown response for document read in Cloud-Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

Currently, I play a bit with firebase and wanted to implement an increment and decrement mechanism. The current value should be stored in Cloud Firestore.

So I made a reference to it and check for the id and if the reference exists.

[image]

When I try to run the code I get back the **correct id** and payload.exist is **true**.

If I want now to add a check if the number is 0 to delete it, the Document Snapshot is **unknown** and so I can't find the property or call delete/update on the document.

[image]

Would be great if anyone could tell me how I get access to the data in the Document.
Thanks! :)

Here you can find the attached code:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }
private updateNumberCount(count: number) {
const reference = this.db.collection('counting').doc('documentId');

reference.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
  console.log(item.payload.id);     // the correct id is displayed
  console.log(item.payload.exists); // -> is true

  const quantity = (item.currentNumber || 0) + count;
  if (quantity === 0) {
    // if it is 0 it should be deleted
    item.delete();
  } else {
    // if it not exists it should be created or updated
    item.update({ currentNumber });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Hello, please add your code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and **not as an image**. With text, it allows the other users to copy/paste it in order to write their answer.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I attached it! :)

Comment: I suggest removing the images entirely and just showing the text of **all** of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the data back by calling **.ref.get().then()** on the referance to the document.

```
const reference = this.db.collection('counting').doc('documentId');

reference.ref.get().then(doc => {
// here I can call **.data** on it to receive the data. 
   doc.data().currentNumber 
}
```

Thank you for all the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges), `snapshotChanges()` returns an Observable of data as a `DocumentChangeAction`.

And for the [`DocumentChangeAction` type](http://The%20DocumentChangeAction%20type):

> A `DocumentChangeAction` gives you the type and payload properties. ... The payload property is a `DocumentChange` which
> provides you important metadata about the change and a `doc` property
> which is the `DocumentSnapshot`.

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
const quantity = (item.payload.doc.data().currentNumber  ...
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud for the quick response! I tried to receive the data with payload.data() and had a look at the documentation (which already helped me a lot!) unfortunately I can't resolve my problem. 
It still tells me it can't resolve the property of type unknown.

I can't find how to make it know in the documentation either ...

Comment: It is `payload.doc.data()` if I am not mistaking, not `payload.data()`.

Comment: doc could not be found either. I found out a different approach that solved the problem. 
Thank you for helping!! :)